# React displaying which item was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

im having a real hard time learning react and I can't quite understand how to solve this problem. I have Tournaments.js which reads tournament names from an API and displays them as clickable elements with a reference to templates.js in which I would like to simply display the name of the element that was clicked.

Tournaments.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const API = 'http://localhost:8080/api/tournaments';

class Tournaments extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API)
    .then((Response) => Response.json())
    .then((findresponse) => {
      console.log(findresponse)
      this.setState({
        data:findresponse,
      })
    })
  }

  testfun(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    console.log(target)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
              {
                this.state.data.map((dynamicData, key) =>
                <div>
                  <a key={dynamicData.id} href={"/#/template"} onClick={this.testfun}>{dynamicData.name}</a>
                </div>
                )
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Tournaments;
```

template.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Tournaments from "./Tournaments";

const API = 'http://localhost:8080/api/tournaments';

class template extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>clicked item</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default template;
```

And my API stores data looking like this:

```
[{"name":"abc","id":1,"organizer":"kla"},{"name":"fsdfs","id":2,"organizer":"fsdf"}]
```

I've tried to use onclick to get the value that was clicked but not sure how to display it in template.js.

Thanks for any help

Comment: put your ``template.js`` inside ``Tournaments.js``, and put ``this.state. data`` as ``props``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to put user clicked item from Tournaments.js and display in Template.js

You can try to put `Template` inside `Tournaments`

**Tournaments.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Template from './template';

class Tournaments extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      clickedData: []
    }
  }

  testfun(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    console.log(target);

    let newClickedData = [];
    newClickedData.push(target);
    this.setState({
       clickedData: newClickedData
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        ...
        <Template clickedData={this.state.clickedData} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}
export default Tournaments;
```

**Template.js**

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from "react";

class template extends Component {
  render() {
    let clickedData = this.props.clickedData;
    let displayClickedData = _.map(clickedData, (item) => {
      return <div>item</div>;
    });

    return(
      <div>
        {displayClickedData}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default template;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest picking one of the following options:

- Wrap both `Tournaments` and `Tournament` in some parent component. Then if you click on any specific tournament, you can change its ID in state. If ID is null, you render list of tournaments, if ID is defined, you render your tournament component. That way you would lose the URL effect.
- You can pass ID as GET parameter in URL and then read it in your Tournament component, so your code would look similar to this `` <a href={`/#/template?id=${dynamicData.id}`}>{dynamicData.name}</a> ``
- You can try out React Router which would handle all that for you